# Left join on same table, analysis on trends mysql

Tags: sql, sql-server

table structure is as follows

```
+---------------+---------+---------+
| customer_name |  date   | balance |
+---------------+---------+---------+
| 123           | june 14 |      20 |
| 123           | june 15 |      30 |
| 1234          | june 14 |      30 |
| 12345         | june 16 |      50 |
+---------------+---------+---------+
```

i would like to join on the same table, keeping my original data set as 2014 and i want to analyse trends to see which customers balance doesnt change from 2014.

for example i would like to show  the below

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| custmomer | june14bal | june15bal |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1234      |        30 |      null |
| 123       |        20 |        30 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have trids multiple left joins but cant seem to get it working. the most important thing is starting my sample with records from 2014 only.

current script

```
with TABLE_DATA as    
(    
select  Customer ,DATE, Balance 
from table   
where dATE in ('30-JUN-2014','30-juN-2015')    
)    
SELECT    
sum(inv1.balance) as year1bal,
suminv2.balance) as year2bal,
customer,
date
from table_datA   inv1 
left  join TABLE_DATA inv2    
on inv1.customer= inv2.customer and inv2.as_of_Date = '30-June-2015'  
group by date, customer
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support CTE (at least not yet).

Comment: Title says "MySQL", tags say "SQL Server" - so which one is it now, really??

Answer (score 0):

you can add having clause after group by Like:

```
having sum(inv1.balance) != sum(inv2.balance)
```

or  try the below query

```
with table2014 as    
(    
select  Customer ,sum(Balance) Balance2014
from tableName 
where dATE ='30-JUN-2014' group by Customer
) 
,Table2015 as
( select  Customer ,sum( Balance) Balance2015
from tableName 
where dATE ='30-juN-2015' group by Customer
)
SELECT    
inv1.customer,Balance2014, Balance2015
from table2014   inv1 
left  join Table2015 inv2    
on inv1.customer= inv2.customer 
--where Balance2014 !=Balance2015
```

Comment: this works, but my balance seems to jump up in year 1, could there be something wrong wit the join? i.e total balance goes higher than the balance in the whole table for 2014

Comment: also why is Balance2014 !=Balance2015 needed? if the balance is the same in botrh years then thats fine

Comment: I thought that you want to show the difference in balance only